# Is it possible to transfer subscriptions, likes, watchlists, and comments from one account to another?

Tags: youtube, google-account, account-management, youtube-channel

In YouTube, is it possible to transfer subscriptions, likes, watchlists, and comments from one account to another?

I don't have a channel or own any original video.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 7 times. The last time was on Jul 5 at 6:01 according to the revisions page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can move a YouTube channel from one account to another account. First step is to move your channel to a Brand Account. Once it is moved, you can add other users and make them the owner.

Move your Brand Account to a different Google Account:

1. On YouTube, sign in as the owner of the Brand Account.
2. In the top right, click your profile picture and then Settings.
3. Under "Account," select Add or remove manager(s).
4. Click Manage permissions.
   Note: You may be asked to enter your password and re-authenticate. Learn more about re-authenticating your account.
   Choose Invite new users .
5. Enter the email address of the Google Account you would like to move your channel to.
6. Below their name, choose their role:
   Owners can take the most actions, and they control who manages the account. An account must have one primary owner.
7. Select Invite  and then Done.
8. Accept the email invite sent to the newly added Google Account.
9. After 7 days, sign in via the new Google Account and return to Manage Permissions.
10. From the drop-down menu, change the signed-in account’s role to primary owner.
11. Click Transfer in the box that pops up.

Refer this [official documentation](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3056283?hl=en&ref_topic=9267586) for more details.